# How to pull an ID from a link the User inputted

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<body>
 <input type="text" id="userINPUT" />
 <button onclick="updatev1()">Submit</button>
   <div id="video1">
    </div>
    <div id="video2">
  </div>
 </body>
```

The html has two divs, and an input text box,and of course, a submit button. What the user is supposed to do is enter a youtube link into the text box, and submit it.

JavaScript:

```
    var userIN1 = document.getElementById("userINPUT");
    var userIN2 = userIN1.value;
    var index = userIN2.substring(string.indexOf('=') -1);
    alert(index);
```

Now what I want the JavaScript to do is to grab the youtube link, and pull the ID from said link.

EX. The user inputs the link. 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K7lEFmFcKs', then the JavaScript would take the link and grab '-K7lEFmFcK' and store it in a variable for later use.

'userIN2' would be the variable that would store the user input value, and 'index' would take the whole ID coming after the '=' symbol of the link and store it.

I know this is considered a small task, but any help would be great.
Thanks!

Oh, and I heard these things can be done A LOT easier with jQuery. Should I use jQuery instead?

Comment: You can't use jQuery instead but you can work with it, because jQuery is JavaScript, it just adds an object which you can use as abstraction layer to often used tools and it add some cross browser compatibility things.

Answer (score 1):

Sure should. It'd be that simple:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var userIN2 = $('#userINPUT').val(); 
    var index = userIN2.split('=');
    index = index[1];
});
```

Comment: PS: it'd be best to give your button an id too, and replace 'button' for '#yourButtonId' in this code. Also, just let me know if you need explanation on any of these lines.

Comment: What if I pass an url like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5waSw2mMfY&x=343#asds`? Then index would additionally contain `&x`, although it's not very  realistic that somebody passes such a YouTube url. You never know what users do.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think it's safe to suppose that no youtube IDs will have another '=' since this would mess the URL parameters.

Comment: @wumm youtube videos will only contain 1 `=`. your code should do validation on user input to make sure the input is correct

Comment: @ashley Yes, I know that, but I sometimes users do strange things. The URL should be validated.

Comment: @ashley Until now I thought too YouTube urls will only contain one GET parameter, but I just clicked on this URL: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=pYwk-ObP1Rw`

Answer (score 0):

This collects everything after `v=`

http://jsfiddle.net/7aZqB/4/

```
function getID(str) {
    return str.substring(str.indexOf('=') -1).replace('v=', '');
}
```